# Why my EditText gets covered by the layout?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, height, android-linearlayout

I have a simple EditText, but when I expand that it gets cut. Maybe my Layout composition is the cause, someone know what the problem is?

My xml file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/surround_paddings"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/surround_margins">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/serverRoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Server 0 - Sala 0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/surround_margins"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_spacing"/>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subject"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
    android:text="@string/subject"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_spacing"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_grey">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_grey"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvMessages"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/surround_margins"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_primary_double"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
                android:dividerHeight="1.3dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:padding="@dimen/surround_paddings"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/commentIcon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_primary_dark_circle"
                    android:src="@drawable/pencil_icon"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/surround_margins"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/questionsNumber"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                    android:hint="@string/wait_your_time"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/surround_margins"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/wait_your_time"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sendIcon"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_accent_circle"
                    android:src="@drawable/pencil_icon"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/surround_paddings"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/surround_margins"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@mipmap/send_icon"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_grey"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="8">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/nextIcon"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/next_icon"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/jump_time"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_spacing"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/negative"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/whose_time"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_spacing"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/negative"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvLine"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/surround_margins"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_grey"
                    android:padding="@dimen/surround_paddings"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:dividerHeight="1.3dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_accent_circle"
                    android:src="@drawable/pencil_icon"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/surround_margins"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the image of what happens when I try to type something: 
[keyboard not expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeFQl.png)

[Here's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djVjV.png)

Idk if this lots of Layouts may be causing it. I thought I should just take enough room to show the whole editText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent this you can add this to your manifest :

```
<activity
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

If this will not work for you you can use this directly inside the xml :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|adjustResize"
```

Sometime this will not solve the problem as well and you will have to add this attribute dynamically:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```